# Migrating Enterprise Postgresql schema to Free Postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, database-migration, enterprise

**Question:** Should we not be able to do something as simple as export the schema from the Enterprise edition and be able to restore it in the free version of Postgresal? And, I cannot find a page that shows/compares the field types that are supported between the two can someone post a link if one exists?

If a direct dump and restore is not an option then I need a suggestion on how to get the dev environment in synch. We have hundreds of tables, schemas, sequences and so forth and no time for me to sit here and go through the system 1 by one checking each column name and configuration, table, etc. as I'm being told that is not one of the tasks that I'm to do.

**Environment:** The production environment is using Enterprise PostgreSql and the Dev environment is using the free version of PostgreSql. We do not have a DBA to answer my question.

**Issue:** The schemas do not match up and I need to get the production schema brought down to the dev environment so I can have some confidence in the environment I'm to work in.
I'm being told by the SA that he had tried to do it before but it was not compatible to bring the Enterprise schema to dev. I don't understand why this is an issue.

Comment: Maybe you should ask the SA why it isn't possible, what are the problems. It's impossible for others to give an answer to that. PostgreSQL is PostgreSQL, schemas are the same. If it's not possible, there must be something else going on.

Comment: Using `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` should do what you want unless you are using features in EnterpriseDB that are not available in Postgres such as PL/SQL procedures or data types that the regular Postgres doesn't have

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I had asked the SA the question of what the errors were and he said that he does not know why. He does not have access to the production database. I don't have access and it is managed by an offsite location. Everything here is a mountain out of a mole hill when trying to get such basic things accomplished.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I just need for them to get me the dmp so I can try for myself and see what is going on. I would think that yes a simple dump and restore is all we need. Fingers are crossed I can get a dmp file this week.

Comment: You should add the exact versions and what products are they, there is no free and enterprise edition of PostgreSQL. There is a company EnterpriseDB and it supplies a fork of pg in paid/free edition. You can refer to https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_derived_databases

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as an "enterprise edition" of PostgreSQL. PostgreSQL is not "open core" or "freemium". It is an open source project and open source product. So that's why you can't find much information about the enterprise edition - it doesn't exist.

I think you're probably talking about [EnterpriseDB Postgres Plus Advanced Server](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/products/postgres-plus-advanced-server). If you're not sure, run `SELECT version()` on the server of interest.

This is a *different thing* to PostgreSQL, a closed-source commercial product *based on* PostgreSQL. It has extensions to PostgreSQL features and syntax that mean EDB PPAS databases are not compatible with community PostgreSQL, though community PostgreSQL databases will generally (always?) be compatible with PPAS. The [postgresql.org](http://postgresql.org) community, except those who work for EDB, have no access to the source code for PPAS, no influence over its features and syntax, etc.

If you're using PPAS, you need to use it consistently across your environment. Or you need to develop in community PostgreSQL only, avoiding using features in PPAS that might render dumps backward-incompatible, and use community PostgreSQL's `pg_dump` when creating dumps from PPAS.

EDB will be able to tell you more, if you are in fact using their product not some other 3rd party fork like Greenplum. See: http://forums.enterprisedb.com/

Note that PPAS is only one of several popular [PostgreSQL-derived products](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_derived_databases), including:

- Greenplum Database
- ParAccel, which is now used by Amazon Redshift

but EDB PPAS is the only one that really stays up to date with core PostgreSQL and remains reasonably compatible.

---

*(Disclosure: I work for a competitor to EnterpriseDB, as shown in my profile, and I contribute to community PostgreSQL)*

Comment: You are correct. I told the SA that I cannot find anything called Postgresql Enterprise edition and he corrected himself that it is called EnterpriseDB Postgres... It helps when I get the correct information the first time instead of wasting time looking for an Apple when it's called an Elephant. Also, I don't have access to the EnterpriseDB only my local Postgresql.